# UIView - Animate with duration seems to ignore duration

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm facing a problem : I have a very simple custom `UIView` which groups one `UITextField` and one `UILabel`.

The `UILabel` is on the `UITextField`, and I want that the `UILabel` go up to 40px when user begins to edit the `UITextField`.

I'm using constraints to set the textfield's frame and the label's frame.

So I just set the delegate in my custom view with `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, and implement the delegate method : `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, as bellow :

I'm just animating the constraint (center Y) of my label in the delegate method.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    self.centerVerticallyLabelConstraint.constant = -40
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
        self.textFieldLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

What happens is that the `UILabel` goes up correctly, but it goes up instantly. It ignores the duration of `0.5` in my animation. I don't know why :

[image: Show problem image]

I'm not animating something else at the same time, I only have this animation.
I haven't disable animations for `UIView.`
The delegate is set to my `UITextfield`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try calling layoutIfNeeded on your view instead of textview.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you... I'm angry to haven't see this before !

Comment: I have been struggling with this for a day. In my case I was animating height constraint of a view, and I was animating it from the view itself. I didn't think at all I had to call the -layoutIfNeeded on the superview. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code to execute:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.textFieldLabel.frame.origin.y -= 40
    }
}
```

Comment: This will break autolayout constraints, which may be undesired. Animating constraints is a valid thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

need to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` not `self.textFieldLabel.layoutIfNeeded()`
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue seems to be because I was already on the main thread & I called the animation block inside a GCD main.async call.

ie I had

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 

<# update the constraint s#>

self.animatedViewsParent.setNeedsLayout() 
animatedView.setNeedsLayout()

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) {
    self.animatedViewsParent.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
}
```

The view animates moves but does not animate gradually over 2.0 seconds. Removing the outer `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` solves the problem.